# Enable USB debugging on Android

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to enable USB Debugging on Android so that I don't need to use the emulator.

I did what all the posts all around the web say to do: I went to `settings -> applications -> Developer -> USB debugging`

It still does not turn on the notification sign that USB Debugging is enabled, and Eclipse does not recognize it, and uses the regular emulator.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  If you use Windows, the USB debugging icon should pop up when you plug it in to the computer, but you probably need to install a driver from the manufacturer in order for Eclipse to recognize the device.

Comment: hi,
i am usign windows 7 with galaxy ace.
what driver do i need to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified what device you are using or what operating system you are using, so that could be helpful.

A few things to keep in mind:

1 Don't mount as USB storage.

2 You also need to make sure to install the drivers for your phone so that the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) can properly communicate.  After these are installed, try the command "adb devices" and you should see an item in your list of devices.

Update based on your comment:  You can download Kies from Samsung, which include the drivers (as well as other things): http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/

Or you can find unofficial driver-only packages, such as: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956

Comment: i am using windows 7 and a samaung galaxcy ace
how do i find these drivers?
where should i run the "adb devices" command from?

Comment: I updated my answer.  Concerning ADB, you run it from the command prompt.  Either add this to your path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools (or wherever your platform-tools folder is) or open a command prompt in that folder directly.

Comment: Alternatively you can navigate to the folder, and right click while holding down shift then select 'Open a command window here'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need the OEM USB dirvers.

Read this:

[OEM USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

My experience with windows has been that you might need to un-install the USB drivers under device manager. Then disconnect the device (restart might be required). After plugging the device back in make sure you use the manufactures drivers if available

Answer (score 0):

you have installed your device driver rite?then right click on your app name->run as->run configurations->target->select manual->apply.after that click on debug button then it will ask you to select the device.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is tested, try with another USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

Fruthermore on some devices you will be asked to accept an RSA key, which allows debugging through your computer. This ensures that other adb commands cannot be executed unless you're able to unlock your device.

Detailed  information can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html It is the overview about adb commands (which is used to send data to your device) and it starts with the steps how to bring your phone to debug-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to add to Danation's answer with the following.

If you have installed KIES, and you've tried following instructions a couple of times (for the android SDK package) without success, here's what worked for me:

As a precaution, disconnect the device, and press 'Revoke USB Debugging authorizations'.
Now, go to kies, and reinstall the device driver as seen on the image below.
Connect the device.

For me, it was a routine, it usually works when installing kies, but I was stuck on this today for a little while, and I hope i can help others with my solution as well..

[image: Reinstall driver button in Kies 3]